# objdump gives the same output for object files generated with and without -fPIC

Tags: c++, gcc, position-independent-code

I have two files, a.h and a.cpp:

```
// a.h
extern "C" void a();

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void a()
{
    printf("a\n");
}
```

I compiled this both with and without `-fPIC`, and then `objdump`ed both.
Weirdly, I got the same output for both files. For `a()`, I get this in both cases:

```
callq 15 <a+0x15>
```

I also tried to compile object files with `-no-pie`, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your code (or anything) in verbose mode (`-v`), inspect the output,
and you will find:

```
Configured with:  ... --enable-default-pie ...
```

which, since GCC 6, means the toolchain is built to compile PIC code and link
PIE executables by default.

To insist on a non-PIC compilation, run e.g.

```
g++ -Wall -c -fno-PIC -o anopic.o a.cpp
```

And to insist on a PIC compilation, run e.g.

```
g++ -Wall -c -fPIC -o apic.o a.cpp
```

Then run:

```
$ objdump -d anopic.o 

anopic.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <a>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <a+0xe>
   e:   90                      nop
   f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  10:   c3                      retq
```

and:

```
$ objdump -d apic.o 

apic.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <a>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # b <a+0xb>
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <a+0x10>
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq
```

and you will see the difference.

You can interleave the relocations with the assembly by:

```
$ objdump --reloc -d anopic.o 

anopic.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <a>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
            5: R_X86_64_32  .rodata
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <a+0xe>
            a: R_X86_64_PC32    puts-0x4
   e:   90                      nop
   f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  10:   c3                      retq
```

and:

```
$ objdump --reloc -d apic.o 

apic.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <a>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # b <a+0xb>
            7: R_X86_64_PC32    .rodata-0x4
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <a+0x10>
            c: R_X86_64_PLT32   puts-0x4
  10:   90                      nop
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: what exactly is the difference here between `mov    $0x0,%edi` and `lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi`? i can also see their addresses are different.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `objdump` does not perform relocation processing.  Try `objdump --reloc` instead.

In your case, the compiler and assembler produce a `R_X86_64_PLT32` relocation.  This is an position-independent relocation.  It seems that your compiler defaults to generating PIE binaries.  `-no-pie` is a linker flag, you need to use `-fno-pie` to change the compiler output.  (In this particular case, it does not matter because the final result will be identical after the link editor has run.)

Comment: the outputs are still exactly the same

Comment: Please show the complete output (the `callq` instruction and a few lines that follow).

Comment: As I said, you have to use `objdump --reloc` to see the relocations.

Comment: and this is the relocations; still the same for both object files: https://ideone.com/MSVq52

Comment: Okay, your toolchain defaults to PIE, and `-no-`pie` does not change that.